# Using enhanced speechResult for </Gather> verb in studio

Tags: twilio, speech-recognition, twilio-studio

There is no option to turn on enhanced option for Speech recognition Result in Studio widgets.

In that case,I guess we have to use twiml redirect to another twiml or Run functuion widgets.

But,if we used that ,how will we return back to studio?
using twiml.redirect and ?FlowEvent=return, with this way?
But where should we use this url to get back to studio?

```
twiml.gather({action:'webhook.twil.io/AC..../FW...xx?FlowEvent=return'
enhanced:true} ,'Hi say your query');
```

But,this actually doesnt return back to studio.
Or should we put url of another function in action  and redirect from that function to  studio?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you redirect out of a Studio flow to use raw TwiML you should do so using the [TwiML Redirect widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect).

To handle returning control to Studio, you need to specify a `<Redirect>` to the Studio Webhook URL and append `?FlowEvent=return`. Any additional parameters specified in the return URL will be injected into the Studio context and addressable via Liquid template variables.

Example:

```xml
<Response>
  <Say>Returning you back to the Studio Flow.</Say>
  <Redirect>https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Flows/{FlowSid}?FlowEvent=return&foo=bar</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Comment: Basically,instead of putting returning link in action, we have to put link of above twiml in action

Comment: Yes, and you can send other parameters back to the flow through the URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [input](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input) attribute:

Try:

```
    twiml.gather({
       enhanced: 'true',
       action: 'https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/AC.../Flows/FW...?FlowEvent=return', 
       input: 'speech'
    }).say('Please say something so enhanced gather can collect and return to Studio');
```